# how to separate one column data into two columns

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

how to separate positive and negative values into two columns from one column.

I have a table `Employee` with a column `Salary` that has positive and negative value. I want to extract two column NegSalary and PosSalary like this:

```
Salary              --->   NegSalary       PosSalary
-1000                       -1000           NULL
 2000                        NULL           2000
 1000                        NULL           1000
 500                         NULL           500
```

Comment: post your try code please

Answer (score 5):

```
select case when col >= 0 then col else null end as pos,
       case when col  < 0 then col else null end as neg
from your_table
```

You can see this here -> http://rextester.com/MCAW87762

Comment: i have used that query bt it doesnt work

Comment: You need to be more specific than that

Comment: actually i have one table which is having positive and negative values into one single column...and i want to display positive values into one column and negative values into another column...plz suggest..

Comment: That is exactly what my query is doing.

Comment: does i have to make a column for neg and pos values?

Comment: Add example data and expected output into your question.

Comment: @Nivedita This answer does exactly what you have asked.

Comment: i have made one table named Employee and having salary column containing positive and negative values...how that query will work..plz elaborate..m not getting query,.

Comment: As I said - edit your question and add example data and expected output to it.

Comment: @Nivedita Check the fiddle. This should give you an idea. Darth Vader can't be wrong. :)

Comment: thank u so much sir...it works.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Case returns NULL if no condition was met.

```
select  case when col >= 0 then col end  as pos
       ,case when col <  0 then col end  as neg

from    mytable
```